# Debug when run a folder

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I have a folder called `cmd`.
When I want to run my program, I need to run the command.
`go run cmd/*.go server` where `server` is an argument.

But I don't know how to setup the debugging for my program in VsCode.
I have tried these configurations but none of these works.

```json
{
  "name": "Launch Package Test",
  "type": "go",
  "request": "launch",
  "mode": "auto",
  "program": "cmd/main.go cmd/initialize.go cmd/commands.go cmd/pubsub_action.go", // all go files in the cmd directory
  "cwd": "${workspace}",
  "args": [
    "server"
  ]
}
```

```json
{
  "name": "Launch Package Test",
  "type": "go",
  "request": "launch",
  "mode": "auto",
  "program": "cmd/*go",
  "cwd": "${workspace}",
  "args": [
    "server"
  ]
}
```

```json
{
  "name": "Launch Package Test",
  "type": "go",
  "request": "launch",
  "mode": "auto",
  "program": "cmd/*",
  "cwd": "${workspace}",
  "args": [
    "server"
  ]
}
```

The question is, what is the correct way to run debugging for my application?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

```json
{
  "name": "Launch Package Test",
  "type": "go",
  "request": "launch",
  "mode": "auto",
  "program": "cmd",
  "cwd": "${workspace}",
  "args": [
    "server"
  ]
}
```

Set the program to `cmd`